# How to add CSS class and control elements inside of the Iframe using javaScript.?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

How to add CSS class and control elements inside of the Iframe using javaScript.

```
<iframe width="340" scrolling="no" height="37" src="http://www.indiansplash.com/business/include/dash11i.php" id="ifr" hspace="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" style="width: 585px; height: 47px; border: #dddddd 1px solid"></iframe>
```

Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/wV8gF/

Here i want to hide first column which are having BSE logo and i want to change the color of values.

Comment: and where do you want the script? inside the iframe page? or from the page that contains the iframe.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe for how to apply CSS to an Iframe

Comment: @Joseph not inside of inframe.

Comment: If _iframe_ contains page from different domain (protocol, server, port) then you maybe need additional permissions to do this. In another case you can get error such as _"permission denied to access..."_ (in FF) or _"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL ..."_ (in Chrome) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It may useful.

http://jsfiddle.net/wV8gF/3/

Comment: Yes. it's working fine. i struck my work with this problem since 4days. Tnq Pan. But how can i change the font colors...

Answer (score 0):

The DOM includes  a frames collection you can access with JavaScript:

You'd need a name attribute on your iframe tag

```
<iframe name = "myFrame"
    width="340" scrolling="no" height="37" 
    src="http://www.indiansplash.com/business/include/dash11i.php" 
    id="ifr" hspace="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" 
    style="width: 585px; height: 47px; border: #dddddd 1px solid">
</iframe>
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
var myFrame = frames["myFrame"]
```

You can apply a new stylesheet to the content by following the example here: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

**UPDATE**

Following the example in the reference i cited above:

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
cssLink.href = "iframeStyles.css"; /* change this to the url for a stylesheet targetting the iframe */
cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink .type = "text/css"; 
frames['myFrame'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Then in `iframeStyles.css`:

```
td{border:1px solid red;} /*or whatever*/
```

You may need a selector with stronger specificity, or apply !important to styles to overide already existing declarations.

Comment: But in your answer i dont get how to append a class to td.

Comment: You don't need a class on the td to be able to apply styles to it. You can apply the styles to all td's in the iframe with: td{/* style delcarations*/}

Comment: Here i want to place two different colors for two td's. in that case your suggestion will not work.

Comment: In your case there are 3 td's. The 3rd, fortunately, has an id. So you can apply a style intended for the middle one with td{/*styles*/}, then override this for the first td with  td:first-child{/*styles*/}, and finally override for the 3rd td with #change{/*styles*/}.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
var my_td = $("#table_id tr td", $("#iframe_ID").contents());
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.