# How to disable the buttons of other URL opening using Iframe?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I m using iframe to open another webservice. there user can view the complete the nav of the targeted link. but i wan't to prevent the user to view the complete nav.

There are five items in the targetd URL like this:

1. Overview
2. Call Log
3. Terrif
4. Payment
5. Logout

   ```
   <iframe id="subframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="login.aspx" style="float: left;height: 754px; margin-left: 118px;  width: 727px;"  ></iframe>
   ```

Now what i want is that, allow user only to view the Call Log.

How could be this possible to do?

Which steps could be taken to perform these all?

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: "other webservice" ??? If it's another domain, you don't have access.

Comment: Markipe. i have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the service is  on your own domain, you can access the frames DOM like so:

```
var myFrame = frames["myFrame"]

var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
cssLink.href = "iframeStyles.css"; /* change this to the url for a stylesheet targetting the iframe */
cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink .type = "text/css"; 
frames['myFrame'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Also see this question:
[How to add CSS class and control elements inside of the Iframe using javaScript.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478251/how-to-add-css-class-and-control-elements-inside-of-the-iframe-using-javascript)

If the iframe loads a page from another domain, you may not alter it, because that would be against the same origin policy.

Comment: is there any mean to upload an image because only users having at least 10 reputation can load the image

Comment: I dont know, but you can link it

Answer (score 0):

I used this a couple of months before.. Some edits might be required:

```
<div id="IframeWrapper">
<div id="iframeBlocker">
</div>
<iframe id="mainframe" src="http://www.xyz.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
#IframeWrapper
{
    position: relative;
}

#iframeBlocker
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 700px;
    height: 450px;
}

#mainframe
{
    overflow: hidden;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

[**OTHER ALTERNATE AND A BETTER ONE**](http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/html5-iframe-attributes.htm)

Comment: is there any mean to upload an image because only users having at least 10 reputation can load the image.

Comment: I don't think so.. Try the link I have given in the answer.. There is a list of new attributes for IFRAME in html5.. otherwise above it is an old css trick which disables all links..