# How to throw the user to a particular page using iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

i have the following two urls

1. www.kadco-international.com
2. www.kadco-international.com/company.html

m using the iframe in asp.net to throw the user to the company.html page but it throw always to the index.html.

Here `is` what I m trying yet: http://jsfiddle.net/Mohsin_Ali/ZqbCK/

**Code:**

```
<iframe width="340" scrolling="no" height="37" 
src="www.kadco-international.com/company.html" id="ifr" hspace="0" 
marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" 
style="width: 585px; height: 47px; border: #dddddd 1px solid" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want? I simply added an http:// to the src.

```
<iframe width="340" scrolling="no" height="37" src="http://kadco-international.com/company.html" id="ifr" hspace="0" marginwidth="0" 

marginheight="0" vspace="0" style="width: 585px; height: 47px; border: #dddddd 1px solid" ></iframe>
```

Comment: or just add '//' to support both case http & https

Comment: yes, its working. but m accessing something other. i have this http://wapi.breathecall.com/myaccount/login. it contain nav1,nav2 and nav3. i want to display only nav2. How could be this possible?

Comment: @user2504141 You mean..its redirecting you to another URL with variable data?  You may want to reverse that as a seperate question on stackoverflow, in how to manipulate URL variable data if that is the case.

Comment: here it is
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207921/how-to-disable-the-buttons-of-other-url-opening-using-iframe